# Bash script for bandwidth interface ports

Tags: linux, bash, shell, snmp

I am looking for a bash script to watch live traffic in Cisco ports. I have Cacti and have a real time monitor to watch what traffic passes on ports. But I don`t need to watch in web interface.

My aim is to make bash script which will get real time traffic for all ports at the same time.

This script is used for live monitoring in Linux

```
#/bin/bash

#purpose: this script can be use to get the report of total band
interface=eth0
community=public
interval=60
server=localhost
clear
echo -e "\033[0m\033[1m\033[5m@@ Network Interfaces Bandwidth Monitor @@\033[0m"
echo "========================================================="
echo -n "Finding interfaces $interface instance details..."
echo
instance=`snmpwalk -v 1 -c $community $server |grep "ifDescr" |grep eth0 | awk -f\. '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`
if [ -z $instance ]; then
echo
echo "Error finding interface from snmp or worng community exit now"
echo
exit 1
else
echo
fi
while true
do
bytes_beforeTOT=0;bytes_afterTOT=0;
bytes_beforeIN=0;bytes_afterIN=0;
bytes_beforeOUT=0;bytes_afteOUT=0; echo -e "Calculating bandwith for $interface during last $interval second interval ....\n"
bytes_beforeIN=`snmpget -v 1 -c $community $server RCF1213-MIB::ifInOctets.$instance | awk '{print $4}'`
bytes_beforeOUT=`snmpget -v 1 -c $community $server RCF1213-MIB::ifOutOctets.$instance | awk '{print $4}'`
bytes_beforeTOT=`snmpget -v 1 -c $community $server RCF1213-MIB::ifInOctets.$instance RCF1213-MIB::ifOutOctets.$instance | awk '{sum+=$4} END{print sum}'` 
sleep $interval 
bytes_afterIN=`snmpget -v 1 -c $community $server RCF1213-MIB::ifInOctets.$instance | awk '{print $4}'`
bytes_afteOUT=`snmpget -v 1 -c $community $server RCF1213-MIB::ifOutOctets.$instance | awk '{print $4}'`
bytes_afterTOT=`snmpget -v 1 -c $community $server RCF1213-MIB::ifInOctets.$instance RCF1213-MIB::ifOutOctets.$instance | awk '{sum+-$4} END{print sum}'`
TOTALIN="$(($bytes_afterIN - $bytes_beforeIN))"
TOTALOUT="$((bytes_afteOUT - $bytes_beforeOUT))"
TOTALTOT="$(($bytes_afterTOT - $bytes_beforeTOT))"
sumkbIN=`echo $TOTALIN/1024 | bc`
summbIN=`echo $sumkbIN/1024 | bc`
sumkbOUT=`echo $TOTALOUT/1024 | bc`
summbOUT=`echo $sumkbOUT/1024 | bc`
sumkbTOT=`echo $TOTALTOT/1024 | bc`
summbTOT=`echo $sumkbTOT/1024 | bc`
echo "Incoming Bandwidth Usage in KB : $sumkbIN KB / $summbIN MB"
echo -e "Outgoing Bandwidth Usage in KB : $sumkbOUT KB / $summbOUT MB"
echo -e "Total Bandwidth Usage in KB : $sumkbTOT KB / $summbTOT MB\n"
sleep 1
done
```

but it is hard to modify for Cisco routers.

I need to watch traffic in all ports real time.

/edit.30-10-2017/

I start from 0 to write script

```
#!/bin/bash

#skrit za analiz na tekushtia triafik posredstvom snmp

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo Usage: "$0" hostname community
        exit 4
fi

server="$1"
commynity="$2"
interval=10
snmp="snmpget -v 2c -c $2 -Cf -Ov -OQ $server"

numports=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifNumber.0`

for i in `seq 1 $numports`; do
        name=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifName.$i`
        if [ "$name" = "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" ]; then
                continue
        fi

        ifInOctets=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifInOctets.$i`
        if [ "ifInOctets" = "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" ]; then
                continue

        fi

        ifOutOctets=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.$i`
        if [ "ifOutOctets" = "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" ]; then
                continue

        fi





done
```

Tomorrow I will update the question with more code. It would be of great help if some one can offer help.

Comment: you should try to call `snmpget` only 1 time in your script, maybe `snmpget -v 1 -c $community $server RCF1213-MIB` to get back all details and then parse it with an awk script. Your current code is running many, many process to produce 1 set of output, You probably need to only call `snmpwalk` 1 time and `smnpget` 1 time as well, and then process all the retrieved data in one script. I don't have access to any hardware that responds to `smnpget` (etc) requests, so I will not be able to help  you with this Q. (Or consider updating your Q with the minimal amt of data ). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

#skrit za analiz na tekushtia triafik posredstvom snmp

if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo Usage: "$0" hostname community
        exit 4
fi

server="$1"
commynity="$2"
interval=2
snmp="snmpget -v 2c -c $2 -Cf -Ov -OQ $server"

numports=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifNumber.0`

for i in $(seq 1 $numports); do
        name=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifName.$i`
        echo "Chek port $name"
        if [ "$name" = "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" ]; then
                continue
        fi


        OUT=$(snmpget -v2c -c $2 $1 IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.$i | awk '{print $4}')
        IN=$(snmpget -v2c -c $2 $1 IF-MIB::ifInOctets.$i | awk '{print $4}')
        TIME=10
        SPEED=`snmpwalk -v 2c -c $2 $1 IF-MIB::ifSpeed.$i | awk '{print $4}'`
        # Use the following variable for 10G ports
        #SPEED=10000000000
        PIPE=100000



        ifInOctets=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifInOctets.$i`
        echo "Show traffic $ifInOctests"
        if [ "ifInOctets" = "No Such Instance currently exists at this OID" ]; then
                continue

        fi

        status=`$snmp IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.$i`


if [ "$status" = "up" ]; then
        sleep $TIME
        IN2=$(snmpget -v2c -c $2 $1 IF-MIB::ifInOctets.$i | awk '{print $4}')
        DELTAIN=$(( $IN2 - $IN))
        INPUTBW=$(((($DELTAIN)/$TIME)*8/1024))
        percentage_use=$(echo "scale=9; $PIPE/$INPUTBW" | bc)
        PRCNTIN=$(echo "scale=0; 100/$percentage_use" | bc)
        PRCNTIN_IF=$(echo $PRCNTIN | tr -d ".")
        echo "Inbound: $INPUTBW kbps"
fi
if [ "$status" = "up" ]; then
        sleep $TIME
        OUT2=$(snmpget -v2c -c $2 $1 IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.$i | awk '{print $4}')
        DELTAOUT=$(( $OUT2 - $OUT))
        OUTPUTBW=$(((($DELTAOUT)/$TIME)*8/1024))
        percentage_use=$(echo "scale=9; $PIPE/$OUTPUTBW" | bc)
        PRCNTOUT=$(echo "scale=0; 100/$percentage_use" | bc)
        PRCNTOUT_IF=$(echo $PRCNTOUT | tr -d ".")
        echo "Outbound: $OUTPUTBW kbps"
        sleep $TIME
fi
if [ "$status" = "down" ]; then
        echo "$name is down"
fi
done
```

This works for now, but i need to filter which port is up and down, and check only up ports. Need to convert from kbps to Mbps. And need to make loop to check in real time every up port and show traffic.